# Android - как "вернуться" в основной поток?

Tags: android, java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте! Я решил сделать одну ресурсоёмкую операцию (метод находится в другом классе) в другом потоке:

---

```
 //MainActivity

public void open_generator(int s) {
    //тут был код, который не имеет отношения к вопросу

    time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Generator.generate(s);
}
```

---

```
//Generator

public static void generate(final int r)
{ 
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //очень много кода

            handler.post(new Runnbale() { //вот тут как бы идёт возвращение в основной поток
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                    ma.finished(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
            });    
        }
    }).start();

}
```

---

```
//и снова MainActivity

public void finished(long at) {
    time_finish = at;
    int time = (int)(time_finish - time_start) / 1000;
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Генерация завершена за " + time + " секунд", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

После запуска этого кода приложение крашится, в логах полная ахинея (ругается на `ContextWrapper`, вызванный от `Toast.makeText(...).show();` ). Я так понял, что я неправильно "вернулся" в основной поток. Даже `runOnUIThread()` не помог. Что делать?

На плюсы не скуплюсь.

Comment: почитай про asyntask, в твоем варианте надо handler делать

Comment: @Gorets, если делать под asynctask, то придётся очень многое переделывать. Неужели нет способа попроще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас проблема не в потоках, а в том, что Вы создаёте новый экземпляр `MainActivity.class` , не имеющий контекста. И при создании `Toast` получаете не "полную ахинею" )), а `NullPointerException`, я полагаю.
      Передайте в метод `generate()` экземпляр Вашей `Activity`:

```
Generator.generate(s, this);
```

и используйте его :

---

```
//Generator

public static void generate(final int r, final MainActivity ma){      
    new Thread(new Runnable() {      
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //очень много кода

            handler.post(new Runnbale() {      
            //вот тут как бы идёт возвращение в основной поток
                @Override
                public void run() {
                /* MainActivity ma = new MainActivity(); // - ошибка здесь*/
                   ma.finished(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
            });    
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Так и сделал! Спасибо!